# Spring Injection - Instances

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, code-injection

I'm new to Spring, but I can't figure out this.
When I call `myMethod` two or more times, `propA` in `myManager` get overwritten and "`doSomething`" is called every time for the same `propA` value (the last setted).
How does Spring injection work? I'd like a new `MyManager` instance every time I call `myMethod()`. Is my approach wrong?

Here is my simplified (and wrong) code:

```
public class myClass {

private MyManager manager;
//..setter and getter 

public String myMethod() {
    //somelogic

    manager.setPropA("a");

    Thread tt = new Thread(manager);
    try {
        tt.start();
    } catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
        log.error("Errore", e);
    }
}
}

public class MyManager implements Runnable {

private MyService service;
private String propA;

//Setters and getters   
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        // sleep(30000);
        service.doSomething(propA);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //ERROR
    }
}
}
```

Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="myClass" class="..." scope="prototype" >
    <property name="manager" ref="MyManager"/>
</bean>


<bean id="MyManager" class="" scope="prototype">
    <property name="service" ref="MyService"/>
</bean>


   <bean id="MyService" class="...">
    <property name="myDao" ref="MyDao" />
</bean>
```

Yes I have @reos .

I ended up with this solution but I was not so happy and changed my code.

Here is my not happy solution, if someone is interested in:

```
public class MyManager implements ApplicationContextAware,  Runnable {

private MyService service;
private String propA;
private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;


public MyManager() {

}

public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return applicationContext;
}

@Override
public  void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}


//Others getters and setters


@Override
public void run() {
try {
    // sleep(30000);
service= (MyService)this.applicationContext.getBean("MyService");
    service.doSomething(propA);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //ERROR
}
}

}


public class myClass {

private MyManager manager;
//..setter and getter 

public String myMethod() {
//somelogic

MyManager manager = new MyManager();
manager.setPropA("propA");

manager.setPropA("a");

Thread tt = new Thread(manager);
try {
    tt.start();
} catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
    log.error("Errore", e);
 }
}
}
```

Comment: It's possible for you to use annotations ?

Comment: How are you getting "myClass" bean?  throught the applicationcontext.getbean ? can you access the applicationcontext ?

Answer (score 1):

this doesn't work that way. Spring injects your code as far as I know only on creation time. So when myClass is created, it will find a reference to myManager that will then also be created so it can be injected. Because of this, your manager will always be of the same instance.

If you want a new instance, I recommend implementing a factory.

```
public class MyManagerfactory {

public MyManager create() { ... // create new instance }

}
```

Instead of injecting your manager directly, you can now inject the factory into MyClass. The factory will then create a new instance of the manager that you can configure and pass to your thread for execution.

If you wanted to do this through spring you would have to create multiple instances of your MyClass instance and pass them different instances of your MyManager. Calling a method does not do injection for you.

You could manually create your beans through the application context, but that would also not be the most ideal solution. I think a factory is what you want in this case.

Hope that helps,

Artur

Comment: I'm not able to try just now, but what should my  `create() ` method do? something like 'return new MyManager();' and where is in this case injection performed?

Comment: The create method would be creating a new instance of your MyManager class. Probably just calling the constructor, not sure, whatever your object needs. The idea is that you want to have a new instance each time you call the factory to create a new instance.

Comment: You can't have injection performed after creation time, as said in answer. The injection would be performed only when the MyManagerFactory is injected in the MyClass.

Comment: Yes, this mean a managerFactory implementation can't resolve my problem. Am I right?

Comment: it will resolve your problem. By insterting the factory, the factory will create new managers for each call. So each manager wikll have their own propA and will not overwrite each other.

Comment: inject your myservice property into the factory and create the managers programatically with the service..

Comment: Ok, now I can understand what you mean! Thanks a lot!